# How to print Slice with comma seperated values in golang

Tags: string, go, format, slice

**INPUT:**

```
    // a slice of type string.
    data := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
["one","two","three"]
```

**I tried with these format specifiers**
https://play.golang.org/p/zBcFAh7YoVn

```
fmt.Printf("%+q\n", data)
fmt.Printf("%#q\n", data)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", data)
// using strings.Join()
result := strings.Join(data, ",")
fmt.Println(result)
```

*Output:*
All values are without a comma,

```
["one" "two" "three"]
[`one` `two` `three`]
["one" "two" "three"]
one,two,three
```

Comment: You _cannot_ do this with fmt.Sprintf , no matter what verb and modifier you use. If you want to generate JSON: Use encoding/json.Marshal. If  no quoting is needed: Construct the string yourself via `["` + strings.Join(data, `","`) + `"]`. If quoting is needed: Write a loop.

Answer (score 9):

JSON generates a nice escaped csv

https://go.dev/play/p/Qgh2WgOvAUW

```golang
data := []string{"1", "2", "A", "B", "Hack\"er"}
b, _ := json.Marshal(data)
fmt.Printf("%v", string(b)) // ["1", "2", "A", "B", "Hack\"er"]
```

Just using `Join` would create corrupted values if the string contains double quotes.

Answer (score 7):

```
// define slice
args := []string{"one", "two", "three"}

// prepend single quote, perform joins, append single quote
output := "'"+strings.Join(args, `','`) + `'`

fmt.Println(output)
```

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/pKu0sO_QsGo

Comment: This doesn't handle strings with quotes properly, for example
`[]string{"o\"ne", "two", "three"}`

Answer (score 2):

Don't know this will help, But just adding my thoughts too !!

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    data := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    //fmt.Println(data)
    for index, j := range data {
        if index == 0 { //If the value is first one 
            fmt.Printf("[ '%v', ", j)
        } else if len(data) == index+1 { // If the value is the last one 
            fmt.Printf("'%v' ]", j)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf(" '%v', ", j)   // for all ( middle ) values 
        }

    }
}
```

OutPut

```
[ 'one',  'two', 'three' ]
```

[PlayGroundLink](https://play.golang.org/p/FRqFbb-3zK3)

Answer (score 1):

```
data := []string{"1",  "2"}

var result string 
if len(data) > 0 {
    result = "\"" + strings.Join(data, "\",\"") + "\""
}
fmt.Println(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading "[Go / How to use GoString in Go](https://articles.orsinium.dev/p/notes-go/gostring/)" from [Gram](https://github.com/orsinium), and considering the [`fmt.GoStringer` interface](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#GoStringer), you could:

- define a [type alias](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_declarations)
- define a `GoString()` method on that type alias, for you to define how you want to print a `[]string`
- use a regular `fmt.Printf("%#v", data)` to print your slice of string

That is ([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/3Hc70z4-pVV))

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type array []string

func (a array) GoString() string {
    res := ""
    for index, j := range a {
        if index == 0 { //If the value is first one
            res = fmt.Sprintf("[ '%v', ", j)
        } else if len(a) == index+1 { // If the value is the last one
            res = res + fmt.Sprintf("'%v' ]", j)
        } else {
            res = res + fmt.Sprintf(" '%v', ", j) // for all ( middle ) values
        }

    }
    return res
}

func main() {

    data := array{"one", "two", "three"}
    fmt.Printf("GoString: >%#v<\n", data)
    //fmt.Println(data)
}
```