# How to get values in slice with Go?

Tags: mysql, arrays, go, type-conversion, slice

For a slice in Go, I want to get all the items in it.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var ids = []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(ids)
}

// [1 2 3]
```

If use these ids search in MySQL, like

```
select * from posts where id IN (ids);
```

Here `ids` should be comma separated numbers as

```
select * from posts where id IN (1,2,3);
```

Is there a fast way to get all the id values but not use `for` loop from slice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print Slice with comma seperated values in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61498687/how-to-print-slice-with-comma-seperated-values-in-golang)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a fast way to get all the id values but not use for loop from slice?

No. All you can do is hide the loop in a function.